# No Response from Send() function when using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send email using a contact form on my web page. I am using the code

```
$msg = $mail->Send();
echo $msg;
```

but nothing is printed out.. Obviously I have all my email/domain settings above these lines. Funny thing is that the email is sending correctly, but I get no response (true OR false) from the send method, thus I cannot run an if statement to redirect to another page according to whether the email has been sent or not..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `$mail->Send()` call with:

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

The most likely reason you're getting no output when you `echo $msg` is because the result is `false`. When you `echo false` it will display nothing. Use `var_dump` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Thank you. This does make sense, but still nothing is printed out. Very strange..

Comment: @heinkasner that is strange indeed. In the class it should always return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Very true what you are saying.. this is the only values it can return